# Why isn't gnome color management having any effect at login?

Tags: login, color-management

Since upgrading to Natty, my carefully produced monitor profiles are not being loaded at login.  As soon as I open gnome color management they kick-in (I don't have to click anything), but I don't want to open it every time.

In my startup applications the following is activiated: gcm-apply --login

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: If I type gcm-prefs, it will open the color management dialogue and apply the profile, but if I type gcm-apply or gcm-apply --login (which is the command I found in startup applications), nothing happens.  I would like the profile applied at login without opening the color management dialogue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe gnome-color-manager is not a part of natty by default, so, maybe you could ask or report the bug to their developers?

Comment: Yes, I can see that's the way to go.  Thank you.